# How much leaf growth is required before chilli seedlings can be re-potted?

Tags: seedlings, repotting, planting-times

How much leaf growth is required before you can re-pot the chilli?

Comment: A picture would help us give you a better answer.  How old are the plants? Are they seedlings?

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour] and [edit] your post to add a picture (use the "sun and mountains" icon above the edit box, or just drag a picture onto the edit box.)

Answer (score 1):

I've heard "as soon as the first 2 true leaves are developed". Water thoroughly just before - this keeps the soil together preventing the destruction of the feeder roots.

[image]
<sub>[source of the image](https://garden.org/courseweb/vegetables/CLASS3/c3p9.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

"Pricking out" to move to other pots (as when you have too many seedlings take in a single pot) can be done (carefully, and with some odds of loss) even when the plant has no true leaves yet.

If it's a single plant in a pot and you're asking when to repot larger, things become more nuanced.

Answer (score 0):

A very useful skill in gardening is to gain some experience turning small plants out of their pots to examine how far the root system has extended through the pot. Turn a pot upside down, holding the plant in place with fingers around the stem where it meets the soil, give the pot a shake and remove the pot upwards so that you can see the roots. If the root ball falls apart in your hands then just replant in the same size pot and wait until the root ball holds together solidly. If all you can see is a dense mat of roots then it should have been repotted long ago, break apart the root mass before planting again in a larger pot.